# How to migrate elasticsearch indices from version 5.6.2 to 6.8?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to update all elasticsearch indices from elasticsearch 5.6.2 to 6.8 version.
I don't want to use X-PACK for migration.
I am not using any elastic products.
So, Is there any proper guideline of way for this migration?

I can do it manually like write new mappings without type for my existing indices and then dump documents from my current indices to new one.
But I've more than 150 indices and it will take time to create new mappings and migrate it manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. Elastic is the company behind Elasticsearch, so by using that you are using an Elastic product ;-)
2. The only upgrade assistant I'm aware of is in the free Basic (X-Pack) version of Kibana. Otherwise you'll have to manually run through the features described in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.0/xpack-upgrade-assistant.html.

Comment: X-PACK have elastic license, X-PACK doesn't contain apache2.0 license.
That's why I don't want to use X-PACK.

Comment: Ok, then you'll have to do it yourself. Out of interest, why? Unless you are a cloud provider there shouldn't be any reason for that?